# compare 2 array of dictionaries for none matched items in python

Tags: python

I have 2 huge array of dictionaries ,that looks similar to :

array1 (errat1  in the code below ):

```
[{'advisory_name': 'CL-SA-2016:0071', 'advisory_type': 'Security Advisory', 'issue_date': '2016-01-26 21:00:00', 'advisory': 'CL-SA-2016:0071'}]
```

the array 2 is similar in structure:(errat2  in the code below )

```
[{'advisory_name': 'CL-SA-2016:2098', 'advisory_type': 'Security Advisory', 'issue_date': '2016-10-23 21:00:00', 'advisory': 'CL-SA-2016:2098'}]
```

if fact there is much more items in the dictionary of course

I am getting the above arrays from API

my code looks like:

```
chnnls = client.channel.listMyChannels(key)
for chnnl in chnnls:
      if  valid_label1(chnnl['label']): #this is regex function to limit the dictionary items to errat1 items only
          errat1 =  client.channel.software.listErrata(key, chnnl['label'])
      if  valid_label2(chnnl['label']): #this is regex function to limit the dictionary items to errat2 items only

          errat2 =  client.channel.software.listErrata(key, chnnl['label'])

matches = []
errat_indexed = {}

for item in errat1:
    errat_indexed[(item["advisory_name"])] = item

for item in errata2:
    if not (item["advisory_name"]) in errat_indexed:
            matches.append(item)

for only in matches:
    print only['advisory_name']
```

my goal is to compare the 2 array of dictionaries   arrata1 and errata2 for only the values of 'advisory_name' ,and get only the values of 'advisory_name' that exits only on errata2 array dictionary . my code doesn't give me Amy results output from the script.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but I'll try: you want all values of `advisory_name` that exist in `errata2` and **do not** exist in `errata1`?

Comment: Are you sure that your first `for` loop is doing what you want? Do you want to set `errat1` and `errat2`, or append to them? Your approach seems to be correct in the later code (although using a `set` for `errat_indexed` would be slightly more efficient and clear).

Comment: lucasnadalutti  you understood me correctly ,  I will glad to get  concrete answer and examples ,thanks .

Answer (score 0):

First, make a `set` of the `advisory_name`s that appear in `errata1`, then go through `errata2` and check the names against that set.

```
e1_names = set(d['advisory_name'] for d in errata1)
e2_names = set(d['advisory_name'] for d in errata2 if d['advisory_name'] not in e1_names)
```